# jQuery: does not add class to tag or instantly removes it, respectively

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

First of all, i am new to jQuery. It is no rocket science to create a simple program, but the effect of the following code doesn't make any sense to me. My intention is that after an element with a class ".button" was clicked a new class should be added to that element. Otherwise - clicking somewhere else - the present new class should be removed. Unfortunately, the code in else is executed, even though the condition is true. What are the flaws of my idea? Could you provide a solution to that problem.

```js
$(function() {
  $("*").click(function() {
    var ret = $(this).hasClass("button");

    if (ret) {
      $(".button").addClass("newclass");
    } else {
      $(".button").removeClass("newclass");
    }
  });

  $("form").on("submit", function() {
    return false;
  })
});
```

```css
.newclass {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="get" action="">
  <input type="text" name="">
  <input type="submit" name="" class="button">
</form>
```

Comment: click event bubbles so if you click on element, it will at least reach any parent which isn't button and so which never get the class `newclass` and so remove it for all the `.button`

Comment: You should use `return false;` to stop event propagation in your click event handler.

Comment: Adding an event handler to every element in the DOM isn't a great idea. If you're doing this because the `.button` elements can be appended at any time, use a delegated event handler

Comment: @ZoliSzabo Thank you! This small addition works great :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`click` events *bubble* from the element that was clicked up through to the document, passing through all elements en route.

So what happens when you click your button is that while the class gets added (because the button has the class `button`), the click bubbles to the `form` (which doesn't) and then to `body` (which doesn't) and then to `html` (which doesn't). Your handler is called at each level, because you've attached it to all elements, and so the last one (`html`) wins.

So the minimal change to your code is to stop propagation (tell the event to stop bubbling) when you handle the click:

```
$("*").click(function(e) {
// Note --------------^

  e.stopPropagation(); // <===

  var ret = $(this).hasClass("button");

  if (ret) {
    $(".button").addClass("newclass");
  } else {
    $(".button").removeClass("newclass");
  }
});
```

Example:

```js
$(function() {
  $("*").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    
    var ret = $(this).hasClass("button");

    if (ret) {
      $(".button").addClass("newclass");
    } else {
      $(".button").removeClass("newclass");
    }
  });

  $("form").on("submit", function() {
    return false;
  })
});
```

```css
.newclass {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="get" action="">
  <input type="text" name="">
  <input type="submit" name="" class="button">
</form>
```

**But**, I would change your approach entirely. Instead of having a handler on **every** element in the DOM, I would just attach to `document` and then inspect `e.target`:

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
// ^^^^^^ --- note --------^

  var ret = $(e.target).hasClass("button");
// Note ------^^^^^^^^

  if (ret) {
    $(".button").addClass("newclass");
  } else {
    $(".button").removeClass("newclass");
  }
});
```

That waits for the click to bubble up to `document.body`, and then looks at where it bubbled from (`e.target`).

Example:

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).click(function(e) {
  // Note ------------------------^

    var ret = $(e.target).hasClass("button");

    if (ret) {
      $(".button").addClass("newclass");
    } else {
      $(".button").removeClass("newclass");
    }
  });

  $("form").on("submit", function() {
    return false;
  })
});
```

```css
.newclass {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="get" action="">
  <input type="text" name="">
  <input type="submit" name="" class="button">
</form>
```

If you were using an element that could have child elements (like `button` instead of `input`), you'd have the situation where the click might originate in a *child* or *descendant* of the button. In that case, you might use `closest` to figure out whether the click passed through a `.button` element en route to `document`:

```
var ret = $(e.target).closest(".button").length;
if (ret) {
    // The element clicked or an ancestor of it has the class...
```

(There we're relying on the fact that `0` is falsy but all other non-`NaN` numbers aren't.)

Example:

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).click(function(e) {
  // Note ------------------------^

    var ret = $(e.target).closest(".button").length;

    if (ret) {
      $(".button").addClass("newclass");
    } else {
      $(".button").removeClass("newclass");
    }
  });

  $("form").on("submit", function() {
    return false;
  })
});
```

```css
.newclass {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="get" action="">
  <input type="text" name="">
  <button class="button">
    Direct <strong>Child</strong>
  </button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! The first variant has no effect, but the second one does the job.

Comment: @OverflowingStack: The first variant works as well, see the live example.

Comment: You're right! That tiny 'e' in the argument list was missing, even though you marked that explicitly, eh :) Thanks once more!

Answer (score -1):

First add a selector to your form like this:

```
<form method="get" action="" class="simpleForm">
<input type="text" name="">
<input type="submit" name="" class="button">
</form>
```

Next target that to listen for any click events, checking that the click has happened on only the inputs.

```
$('.simpleForm').unbind('click').bind('click', function(e) {
    if($(this).hasClass('button') && e.target.tagName === 'input') {
        $(this).addClass("newclass");
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass("newclass");
    }
});
```

Comment: You didn't answer his question. He also wants to know what's wrong with his solution...

Comment: Thank you for your efforts anyway!